# "Plan B" contraceptive

Tags: morality, contraception

If a person uses a "Plan B" contraceptive to prevent pregnancy without knowing it may inhibit implantation, is he a murderer?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. For a question like this Christians would give different answers. Some Christians are opposed to all forms of contraception, some would allow for certain techniques which others would consider abortion (and some probably would excuse abortion generally.) So the question is: *whose* answer to this question do you want?

Comment: If you want a definitive answer, restricting the question to the Catholic church will probably give one.